# I would rather he should do it

Tags: construction

> I would rather he should do it.

Is it OK to use "should" after "would rather"? If it's OK, are these OK?

> I would rather he should have done it.

> I would rather he should have be doing it.

PS: I never meant this "I would rather he should have be doing it." it's a typo.

I meant "I would rather he should be doing it."

Answer (score 0):

Not unless what you are trying to say is that, for example, some rule should be changed so that the responsibility for 'doing it' falls to 'him'.

*"I would rather he should have done it."* no, it depends exactly what you are trying to say, but probably: *"I would have preferred it if he had done it."*

*"I would rather he should have be doing it."* - no, again it depends if you are talking about rules or protocols, or simply what you would prefer.

For a rule: *"I would rather it was his responsibility"*

For a preference *"I would rather he did it."*

Comment: Or: I would rather he do it. Present simple.